# Function with similar properties

Tags: functions, notation

Suppose I have a function $f$ and derive another function from it with similar properties. For example I have that my new function is zero when the other function is zero.

I would still like to use the same letter for the new function.
I could for example for something like $\dot f$ or $\breve f$, but I probably need another symbol above the $f$.

What symbol is normally used to denote that we have a function which is equivalent to a given $f$ in some respects?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single fixed symbol, but it's common to use $\tilde{f}$ or $\overline{f}$ in such cases (e.g., for extensions of a given function $f$).

Comment: $overline{f}(z)$ usually stands for the complex conjugate of $f(z)$. $dot{f}(t)$ often stands for the derivative of $f(t)$ wrt to $t$. So care must be taken when use these two symbols.

Comment: `\widetilde{f}` is often used for a function approximating $f$, but if there's no better option I will go for this one.

Comment: I should also have mentioned `\hat{f}` as another option, although that's often used for the Fourier (or similar) transform.